# Can't inject HttpServletRequest into ContainerRequestFilter with Javal 11, Jetty and Jersey

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I am updating a Java 8 web service to run on Java 11. I am not familiar with Java, I am more conversant with the C# dotnet environment. I have read dozens of articles and questions relating to this issue, and I'm pretty convinced that my code should work, but that my project setup is wrong.

My original project only had an Eclipse project file, I've added Maven, and reorganised my project so that I can build an exploded WAR and debug from there. At present, the offending code looks as follows:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    private jakarta.inject.Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider;
    
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext filterContext) throws IOException {
        var servletRequest = requestProvider.get();
    }
}
```

This gives me an error such as:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to create a Proxy for jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest in scope org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped an error occured while creating the proxy
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SocketChannelEndPoint$1.run(SocketChannelEndPoint.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.produce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to create a Proxy for jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest in scope org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped an error occured while creating the proxy
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:410)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1292)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)
    ... 16 more
```

My original code looked like this:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext filterContext) throws IOException {
    }
}
```

Which gave the same two exceptions plus another 4. The @Inject approach causes exception when the action is called, @Context causes exception when the server starts, but in either case it's clear that the httpServletRequest cannot be supplied by the DI Container/Scope.

I'm not 100% sure how all of the bits work together, but if I have it right, the application uses a Jetty 11.0.6 self-hosted web server, with a Jersey 3.0.2 Container, running Jakarta Platform 9.1.0 - Servlet API V5.0, and Jakarta JAXB Web Services. I think that I'm missing a dependency, but I have not been able to determine what it is. Here are my POM and Web.xml files:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Demo-Server</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo-Server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Demo Server</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>16</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.12</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" version="5.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.demo.bridge.app.Application</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/demo/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webts/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.demo.rest.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I really hope that somebody knows what I'm missing. FYI - I have left all of my current dependencies in my POM, not just those that I think are related, because it may be that I have multiple dependencies in place that are causing the issue.

The server boot code is harder to cleanup, but I can post it if necessary - the main bit is a WebAppContext, which does seem to read teh Servlets - also the servlets do respond if I don't use @Context, they just crash because of the null references or bad DI setup.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

--Update--

I've been switching in and out some Maven dependencies. I'm pretty sure that I have the basic dependencies for Jetty, Jakarta, JAXB and Jersey, but I'm still getting the issue with @Context/@Inject. I can tell that I absolutely need the org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2 package because if I leave it out I get an error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.**. If I also add jakarta.inject:jakarta-inject-api, I still get the original error.

So basically I have two injection packages, and the @Context/@Inject don't work with either or both of these present. I'm wondering if Jakarta 9 requires some setup code, but I don't see any in any examples.

My pom dependencies now look like this - still no joy (I've also left out application deps):

```
        <!-- Jakarta -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Latest Update:

So I switched back to OpenJDK 8, expecting the project to run, and it turns out that it doesn't work. Whne comparing the Jars with the original project, I notice that my new program has different Jars. Looking further, the existing project does not have HK2 files, but these are shipped in the jersey-common package.

Does anybody know how to have Jersey in the project without shipping the HK2 jars, because the injection of HttpServletRequest works without them?

Mark

Comment: I was just thinking - I've been searching GitHub and all that I can find are javax.servlet based projects. If anybody could point me in the direction of an example app that implements a Java 11 Jakarta EE servlet with a Jersey container that might be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue was way too hard to get working because the way that elements interact between Jetty, Jakarta and Jersey are all behind the scenes at runtime, i.e. the program successfully compiles with any number of permutations that don't work.

Anyhow, after around 7 days of experimentation, the collection of packages that allow injection of HttpServletRequest to work are as follows:

```
        <!-- Jakarta -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-jakarta-servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.1</version>
          <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I discovered the issue by compiling my original project in Java 8 (as it was before I added Maven) and I found that my non-Maven project did not output 3 hk2 related libraries, hk2-api-2.2.0-b21.jar, hk2-locator-2.2.0-b21.jar, hk2-utils-2.2.0-b21.jar. Deleting these files allowed the program to run properly.

I then tried using dependency exclusion, but even though I ended up with the same libs, the program wouldn't work. Now I'm not quite sure how this works, but I remember reading that dependencies can be scoped to 'provided' which is to say (if I understand correctly) - that the required class implementations already exists in some libraries that you already have (like the JRE or other dependency) so you don't have to include the libraries again.

Again - I don't get precisely why this works, but it absolutely has to be set up like this. I really hope that this saves somebody a few days!